# Fetching Featured Posts with Review and Tag Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have 4 Eloquent.

```
class Featured extends \Eloquent {

    protected $fillable = array('*');
    public function courses() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Course');
    }
}

class Course extends \Eloquent {
    protected $fillable = array('*');
        public function featured() {
            return $this->hasMany('Course');
        }
        public function review() {
            return $this->hasMany('Course');
        }
        public function tag() {
            return $this->hasMany('Course');
        }
}

class Tag extends \Eloquent {

    protected $fillable = array('*');
    public function courses() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Course');
    }
}

class Review extends \Eloquent {

    protected $fillable = array('*');
    public function courses() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Course');
    }
}
```

I need to fetch all the featured courses, their review and tags.

Is it possible in 1 query? I have to show some featured posts on front page with their respective reviews and their tags.

This is Laravel 4.

Comment: Laravel 4 when Laravel 5.1 is out? Are you for real?

Comment: Does , that really matter, can't i use laravel 4 until php 5.4 / 5.5 is supported ?

Comment: why are you using \ before eloquent ? In Controller you need.  Course::with('review')->with('tags')->get()? I think?

Comment: @Rajlaksh , How to get only featured course with review and tags ?

Comment: Course::where('feature',1)->with('review')->with('tags')->get() ?

Comment: `where('feature', 1)` , Actually i have separate pivot table for featured course. Do you suggest me to add featured as a column in course table ?

Comment: No , it is same relation like tags and review. Kindly check my first eloquent in question.

Comment: Feature::with('course')->with('review')->with('tags')->get() ?

Comment: Getting Erro : `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::review()`

Comment: i used your `where('feature', '1')` option, i got the value but they are only from post table, there is no value from review and tags table.

Comment: I got it working can you please use as answer @Rajlaksh `Course::where('feature',1)->with('review')->with('tags')->get() ` , so that i can accept it.

Comment: Okay, I'm adding it in Answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

Course::where('feature',1)->with('review')->with('tags')->get();

feature is a Column which tell course is feature or not.